# RNN regression using Tensorflow?

Tags: python-2.7, audio, tensorflow, regression, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently trying to implement a RNN for regression. 
I need to create a neural network capable of converting audio samples into vector of mfcc feature. I've already know what the feature for each audio samples is, so the task it self is to create a neural network that is capable of converting a list of audio samples in to the desired MFCC feature.

The second problem I am facing is that since the audio files I am sampling has different length, will the list with the audio sample also have different length, which would cause problem with the number of input I need to feed into to the neural network. I found [this post](https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/) on how to handle variable sequence length, and tried to incorporate into my implementation of a RNN, but seem to not be able to get a lot of errors for unexplainable reasons..

Could anyone see what is going wrong with my implementation?

Here is the code:

```
def length(sequence): ##Zero padding to fit the max lenght... Question whether that is a good idea.
    used = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(sequence), reduction_indices=2))
    length = tf.reduce_sum(used, reduction_indices=1)
    length = tf.cast(length, tf.int32)
    return length

def cost(output, target):
    # Compute cross entropy for each frame.
    cross_entropy = target * tf.log(output)
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy, reduction_indices=2)
    mask = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(target), reduction_indices=2))
    cross_entropy *= mask
    # Average over actual sequence lengths.
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy, reduction_indices=1)
    cross_entropy /= tf.reduce_sum(mask, reduction_indices=1)
    return tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

def last_relevant(output):
    max_length = int(output.get_shape()[1])
    relevant = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(output, tf.expand_dims(tf.one_hot(length, max_length), -1)), 1)
    return relevant

files_train_path = [dnn_train+f for f in listdir(dnn_train) if isfile(join(dnn_train, f))]
files_test_path = [dnn_test+f for f in listdir(dnn_test) if isfile(join(dnn_test, f))]

files_train_name = [f for f in listdir(dnn_train) if isfile(join(dnn_train, f))]
files_test_name = [f for f in listdir(dnn_test) if isfile(join(dnn_test, f))]

os.chdir(dnn_train)

train_name,train_data = generate_list_of_names_data(files_train_path)
train_data, train_names, train_output_data, train_class_output = load_sound_files(files_train_path,train_name,train_data)

max_length = 0 ## Used for variable sequence input

for element in train_data:
    if element.size > max_length:
        max_length = element.size

NUM_EXAMPLES = len(train_data)/2

test_data = train_data[NUM_EXAMPLES:]
test_output = train_output_data[NUM_EXAMPLES:]

train_data = train_data[:NUM_EXAMPLES]
train_output = train_output_data[:NUM_EXAMPLES]
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#----------------------------Main--------------------------------------#
### Tensorflow neural network setup

batch_size = None
sequence_length_max = max_length
input_dimension=1

data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[batch_size,sequence_length_max,input_dimension])
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,14])

num_hidden = 24 ## Hidden layer
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden,state_is_tuple=True)  ## Long short term memory

output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, data, dtype=tf.float32,sequence_length = length(data))  ## Creates the Rnn skeleton

last = last_relevant(output)#tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1) ## Appedning as last

weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, int(target.get_shape()[1])]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[target.get_shape()[1]]))

prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias)

cross_entropy = cost(output,target)# How far am I from correct value?

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer() ## TensorflowOptimizer
minimize = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

mistakes = tf.not_equal(tf.argmax(target, 1), tf.argmax(prediction, 1))
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(mistakes, tf.float32))

## Training ##

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

batch_size = 1000
no_of_batches = int(len(train_data)/batch_size)
epoch = 5000
for i in range(epoch):
    ptr = 0
    for j in range(no_of_batches):
        inp, out = train_data[ptr:ptr+batch_size], train_output[ptr:ptr+batch_size]
        ptr+=batch_size
        sess.run(minimize,{data: inp, target: out})
    print "Epoch - ",str(i)
incorrect = sess.run(error,{data: test_data, target: test_output})
print('Epoch {:2d} error {:3.1f}%'.format(i + 1, 100 * incorrect))
sess.close()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_test.py", line 177, in <module>
    last = last_relevant(output)#tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1) ## Appedning as last
  File "tensorflow_test.py", line 132, in last_relevant
    relevant = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(output, tf.expand_dims(tf.one_hot(length, max_length), -1)), 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2778, in one_hot
    name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1413, in _one_hot
    axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 454, in apply_op
    as_ref=input_arg.is_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 621, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 180, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 163, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 421, in make_tensor_proto
    tensor_proto.string_val.extend([compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 45, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <function length at 0x7f51a7a3ede8>
```

**Edit:**

Changing the tf.one_hot(lenght(output),max_length) gives me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_test.py", line 184, in <module>
    cross_entropy = cost(output,target)# How far am I from correct value?
  File "tensorflow_test.py", line 121, in cost
    cross_entropy = target * tf.log(output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 754, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 903, in _mul_dispatch
    return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1427, in mul
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2312, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1704, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1801, in _BroadcastShape
    % (shape_x, shape_y))
ValueError: Incompatible shapes for broadcasting: (?, 14) and (?, 138915, 24)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tf.one_hot(length, ...)
```

here length is a function, not a tensor.  Try length(something) instead.

Comment: `last_relevant` is suppose to extract the output that is relevant meaning that which hasn't be zero padded which would then make sense to feed it `length (output)` which then gives me a new error message.